# Inserting Data from Excel to Acess with VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to run code to connect to a database and insert into a table in that database. The connection works fine, but when I run the code it just copies the data table in access into itself. So if nothing is there I get nothing in return. But if one line of data is there I will get two, then 4, then 8, etc on each consecutive time I run the code.

Table I am inserting into is called `PurchasedInventory`. Named range in Excel is also called `PurchasedInventory`, which is a dynamic range.  Changing the named range to be something other than `PurchasedInventory` does not solve the problem.

```
Public Function connectdatabase()
Set DBCONT = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
Dim strDBpath As String
strDBpath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Brett\Desktop\LupeProject\LupeProject.accdb"
Dim sConn As String
sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & strDBpath & ";" & _
        "JET OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" & _
        "Persist Security Info=False;"

DBCONT.Open sConn

DBCONT.Execute "INSERT INTO PurchasedInventory IN 'C:\Documents and Settings\Brett\Desktop\LupeProject\LupeProject.accdb' SELECT * FROM[PurchasedInventory]"

End Function
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `IN` part of your insert statement. It looks like its ignoring it and just inserting `SELECT * FROM [PurchasedInventory]` instead, which is of course the same table.

Comment: That is what is happening. But how do i get the named range from Excel to populate the access table? There has to be some way to show it the correct table.

Comment: This one shows one method using `transferspreadsheet` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578518/import-different-excel-files-into-ms-access-2010-tables-automatically. This one shows with ADO: http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=173:import-export-data-from-access-to-excel-using-ado&catid=79&Itemid=475

Comment: I see those links, but that is using loops, there should be an elegant way to use an insert into statement that references excel range to solve the issue. ty

Comment: Your connection string builds a path to the Access database but there is no ADO connection to the Excel table (or rows or columns). The connection to the Excel object is not implicit like the `CurrentDb` object in Access VBA.

Comment: You could create the excel range as a linked table and insert it that way.